# How to return PDF and display web page simultaneously in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller with an action which is hit simply to return a PDF to the user. After I return the PDF, I would like to display a Thank You page. When I try to do this, however, I get the following message:

"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."

Is there any way to do this?

Here is the code that returns the PDF:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", outputFile));
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(outputFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

I have created a simple view for the Thank You page. Can I stuff it into the response somehow?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return a jquery function as content which calls for 2 links. 1 the pdf and the otherone pops up a page. You have to call for the pdf first.